# ¿Que estoy haciendo mal al colocar los parámetros de los métodos y guardar en la Hashtable?

Tags: java

Soy bastante nuevo en Java y en programación en general.

Estoy montando un pequeño proyecto que me han pedido en la universidad sobre una App que gestione un parking. El problema se me presenta cuando creo los métodos, podéis notar que los parámetros que les coloco son, en el caso del primer método, para dar Alta y guardar en una Hashtable, una variable tipo String(Será la matrícula leída por Scanner) que se asignará como la key y un objeto de tipo usuario que será el value.

En el otro método, dar la baja, se recibe como parámetro un String que será la misma matrícula, la idea es que previamente habiendo guardado la matrícula en el método Alta, luego se le de la baja a toda la fila key-value de la Hashtable.

El programa compila pero no hace lo pedido, es como que si las variables que pido al usuario nunca se guardaran como parámetros de los métodos tal como los he planteado. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Aquí los códigos:

**Primero la clase Parking con los métodos:**

```
package ProyectoFinalParking;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author JOELS
 */
public class Parking {

    //Como Atributo creamos una Lista que luego sera definida como Hashtable
    private Hashtable<String,Usuario> usuarios;

    //Constructor
    public Parking(){
        this.usuarios= new Hashtable<String,Usuario>();

    }

    //Creo metodo para dar de alta
    public void alta(String a, Usuario usuario){
        this.usuarios.put(a, usuario);
    }

    //Metodo para dar de baja a partir de la key
    public void baja(String b){
        if(this.usuarios.containsKey(b) && this.usuarios!=null){
           this.usuarios.remove(b);
           System.out.println("Vehiculo dado de baja satisfactoriamente");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Matricula no encontada");
        }

        }
```

---

**Ahora la clase main:**

```
package ProyectoFinalParking;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author JOELS
 */
public class AppParking {
public static void main (String[] args){

Parking parking = new Parking();

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int opcion=0; 

do{
System.out.println("Bienvenido al Parking Prosperidad-Indique la opcion deseada");
System.out.println("1-Dar de alta a usuario");
System.out.println("2-Dar de baja a usuario");
System.out.println("3-Registrar entrada");
System.out.println("4-Registrar salida");
System.out.println("5-Mostrar vehiculos");
System.out.println("0-Salir del sistema");
opcion=teclado.nextInt();


Usuario u = null;

switch(opcion){
    case 1: //Dar de alta a usuario
    System.out.println("Nombre: ");
    teclado.nextLine();
    String nombre=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Telefono: ");
    String telefono=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Matricula: ");
    String matricula=teclado.nextLine();


    //Preguntar si los datos son correctos
    System.out.println("¿Son correctos los datos? Nombre: "+nombre+ " Telefono: "+telefono+" Matricula: "+matricula);
    System.out.println("Pulse 1 si es correcto / Pulse 2 si es incorrecto");
    int pulsar=teclado.nextInt();
    switch(pulsar){
        case 1:
         u= new Usuario(nombre,telefono,matricula);
         parking.alta(matricula,u);
         System.out.println("Los datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente");
         break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Vaya a menu principal y repita la carga de datos");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");
    }
        break;


    case 2: //Dar de baja a usuario
        System.out.println("Indique matricula del vehiculo a dar de baja:");
        String b=teclado.nextLine();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("¿Desea dar de baja Matricula: "+b+" ?  Pulse 1 para Si / Pulse 2 para No");
        int pulsarMatricula=teclado.nextInt();
        switch(pulsarMatricula){
            case 1:
                parking.baja(b);


                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Baja cancelada / Volviendo a menu principal");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");

        }



    break;

    case 3: //Registrar entrada

        break;

    case 4: //Registar salida

        break;

    case 5:


    default:
        System.out.println("Saliendo");

}
}while(opcion!=0);


}    
}
```

**Clase Usuario:**

```
@author JOELS
 */
public class Usuario {
    private String nombre;
    private String telefono;
    private String matricula;

    public Usuario(){    
    }


    public Usuario(String nombre, String telefono, String matricula){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.matricula=matricula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuarios{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", matricula=" + matricula + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Usa HashMap en lugar de Hastable, esta última es muy antigua y está desaconsejada desde hace muchos años. No afecta al comportamiento de tu programa pero deberías acostumbrarte a no usar esa clase

Comment: Hola Pablo, ¿El HashMap solucionaría mi problema?

Comment: podrás agregar la clase Usuario. Para verlo completo.

Comment: Ya la coloco @AlbertoLopez

Comment: @AlbertoLopez listo, colocada.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlbertoLopez, problema solucionado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joels,

```
int pulsar=teclado.nextInt();
```

Este método de scanner necesita un nextLine() para poder leer el siguiente campo.

En tu clase AppParking tienes esto:

```
switch(opcion){
    case 1: //Dar de alta a usuario
    System.out.println("Nombre: ");
    teclado.nextLine();  <<< ESTO ESTA HACIENDO QUE PUEDAS LEER EL NOMBRE 
    String nombre=teclado.nextLine();
```

Sin embargo para bajas tienes:

```
case 2: //Dar de baja a usuario
    System.out.println("Indique matricula del vehiculo a dar de baja:");
    String b=teclado.nextLine();
    teclado.nextLine();  <<<ESTO REQUIERES MOVERLO ANTES DE LEER LA MATRÍCULA DEL VEHICULO
```

Quizás lo más fácil es quitar esos dos teclado.nextLine() y ponerlo despues de leer la opción:

```
System.out.println("0-Salir del sistema");
opcion=teclado.nextInt();
teclado.nextLine();  // <<<para no tener que ponerlo dentro de cada case
```

Por otro lado, en altas yo no pasaría de parámetro la matrícula, ya que el usuario tiene una propiedad matrícula:

```
   public void alta(String a, Usuario usuario){
       this.usuarios.put(a, usuario);
   }
```

esto lo cambiaría por :

```
   public void alta(Usuario usuario) {
       this.usuario.put(usuario.getMatricula(), usuario);
   }
```

es solo una opinión.

saludos

Comment: Gracias! @AlbertoLopez, aplicare los cambios sugeridos y te comento.

Answer (score 0):

He visto que en tu clase Parking, en el método **baja**, tienes el `if-else` fuera de las llaves. Ahora veo que lo has corregido. Te faltan algunos `break` en el `switch`. Aunque uses `default:`, la documentación de Java indica el uso de `break` en este, así que por qué no agregarlo?. Puedes verlo aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Otra cosa importante, por qué usas `Hashtable`? debes usar `HashMap`. Hay varias diferencias entre `HashMap` y `Hashtable` en Java. Seguro puedes buscarlo en Google pero, en resumen rápido el `Hashtable` está sincronizado, mientras que `HashMap` no lo está. Esto hace que `HashMap` sea mejor para las aplicaciones sin subprocesos, ya que los Objetos no sincronizados generalmente funcionan mejor que los sincronizados. Repito, un poco de Google sobre la diferencias de ambas y verás las diferencias exactas y el por qué una es mejor que la otra en diferentes escenarios.

Tu código funcionando con `HashMap` y arreglado los errores que he visto (lo he resumido para no hacerlo muy largo y solo he dejado los comentarios sobre los cambios que he hecho):

**Clase Parking**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Parking {

    private HashMap<String, Usuario> usuarios;

    public Parking() {
        this.usuarios = new HashMap<String, Usuario>();

    }

    public void alta(String matricula, Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuarios.put(matricula, usuario);
    }

    public void baja(String b){
        // Aquí debe de ir
        if(this.usuarios.containsKey(b) && this.usuarios!=null){
               this.usuarios.remove(b);
               System.out.println("Vehiculo dado de baja satisfactoriamente");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Matricula no encontada");
            }
    }

    /* POR QUÉ ESTÁ ESTO FUERA DEL MÉTODO "baja"?
        if(this.usuarios.containsKey(b) && this.usuarios!=null){
           this.usuarios.remove(b);
           System.out.println("Vehiculo dado de baja satisfactoriamente");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Matricula no encontada");
        }
        */

    /**
     * Getter para obtener los datos del HashMap
     */
    public HashMap<String, Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }
}
```

**Clase AppParking**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppParking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parking parking = new Parking();

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Bienvenido al Parking Prosperidad-Indique la opcion deseada");
            System.out.println("1-Dar de alta a usuario");
            System.out.println("5-Mostrar vehiculos");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();

            Usuario u = null;

            switch (opcion) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                teclado.nextLine();
                String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Telefono: ");
                String telefono = teclado.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Matricula: ");
                String matricula = teclado.nextLine();

                System.out.println("¿Son correctos los datos? Nombre: " + nombre + " Telefono: " + telefono
                        + " Matricula: " + matricula);
                System.out.println("Pulse 1 si es correcto / Pulse 2 si es incorrecto");
                int pulsar = teclado.nextInt();

                switch (pulsar) {
                case 1:
                    u = new Usuario(nombre, telefono, matricula);
                    parking.alta(matricula, u);
                    System.out.println("Los datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Vaya a menu principal y repita la carga de datos");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Volviendo a menu principal");
                    break; // Falta este break
                }
                break;

            case 5: // Imprimir HashMap
                // Obtener datos del HashMap
                HashMap<String, Usuario> usuarios = parking.getUsuarios();

                // Iterar a todas las claves almacenadas en nuestro HashMap
                for (String s : usuarios.keySet()) {

                    System.out.println("\nMatricula: " + usuarios.get(s).getMatricula() + "\n" + 
                    "Nombre: " + usuarios.get(s).getNombre() + "\n" + 
                            "Telefono: " + usuarios.get(s).getTelefono() + "\n");
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Saliendo");
                break; // Falta este break
            }
        } while (opcion != 0);

        // Cerrar el Scanner
        teclado.close();

    }
}
```

Tu clase Usuario se mantiene igual, espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Gracias! @Robert Gomez, aplicare los cambios sugeridos y te comento.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Robert Gomez, problema solucionado!

Comment: @JoelsHidalgo estamos para ayudarte. Si mi respuesta ha sido tu solución, no olvides seleccionar mi respuesta como la Aceptada y votar por ella. Saludos.